# Splash Screen for Cross Platform

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform

i want to create a splash screen for my cross platform application when i follow this tutorial https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/
it says that i need to add go to  Resources > Values > styles.xml create your splashscreen theme.

[image: Pic attached here]

shows that that i don't have value> style.xml in my android project. can anyone advice how can i fix this issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create the "values" directory under "Resources" and add "styles.xml".

[Here](http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=294) another sample

Comment: Please include relevant parts of what you link to in your own question. As it is now your answer is a link only answer and does not fit well for the QA style Stack Overflow provides.

Comment: It's not a Link Only answer. The answer is to create the directory and the file. The link it's only another document , but the question is already answered, dear @Cheesebaron